# How to display only month and year in a custom date field in vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to know how we can implement a custom date field in vf page which will display only month and year.

Regards

Comment: Sid does my ans helped ?

Comment: Hi Ratan.. Sorry for the delay..i am looking for inputtext from user...the user is going to do the input by selecting the month and year..outputtext is used for displaying the date..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this.. instead `{!now()}` pass your custom field `{!CutomObject.FieldAPIName__c}`

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM','  yyyy}">
      <apex:param value="{!now()}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

Output

[image]